# Include an extension in your template name, including ".twig" (e.g. robots.txt.twig)

Tags: templating

I like to use `.twig` for my templates for easy syntax switching, but it doesn't seem to work when my template requires an extension as part of its name.

For instance:

- `robots.txt` works fine
- `robots.txt.twig`, doesn't. The matching request is now `{siteUrl}/robots.txt.twig`, and I don't get the automatic `Content-Type` matching that happens when it is just `robots.txt`.

I figure this just isn't currently supported, but I would be nice!

Comment: Curious... what's the use case for using a double extension?  i.e. Why not just use robots.twig?

Comment: Well, in the case of `robots.txt`, because it _has_ to be accessible from `/robots.txt`. So to use `robots.twig` you'd have to set up a route. And with the `.txt` in the template name, you get the `content-type` header automatically set.

Comment: @TimKelty We made this possible in Craft 2.2. Updated my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because right now, if your template path includes an extension, Craft assumes that you’re explicitly providing the full template path, and won’t try appending the [defaultTemplateExtensions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#defaultTemplateExtensions) to it. (See a full explanation [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#findTemplate-detail).)

robots.txt does make a good use case for why we should append those extensions anyway, though. We shall consider it :)

**UPDATE**

We changed this behavior in Craft 2.2, so now a request to /robots.txt could resolve to a template called /robots.txt.twig. http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2579

Comment: The 2.2 update is great, and allows us to name things `robots.txt.twig`, `entries.json.twig`...However, we now unfortunately miss out on the `Content-type` detection that we would get if we had the templates names without the `.twig` on the end. Too much to ask? :)

Comment: `.twig` files are always going to default to HTML. You can explicitly set the MIME type using the [{% header %}](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/header) tag though: `{% header "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" %}`

Comment: If you are setting up sitemap.xml.twig
`{% header "Content-Type: text/xml;" %}`
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`